# How to make a function definition in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

The following works as expected with print but as soon as I try to use Def and return to create a function I get the following error.

> SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

It doesn't work whatever I do or wherever I place the return.  I am apparently missing some essential knowledge concerning functions. Where am I going wrong?

```
def two_teams(sailors):

        sailors ={'Smith': 34,'Wesson': 22,'Coleman': 45,'davies' : 50,'Abrahams': 19, 'Toms': 23}                                                                                                                           

firstShip =[]

secondShip = []

for i in sailors.keys():
    if sailors[i] > 40 or sailors[i] < 20:
        firstShip.append(i)
        firstShip.sort()


    else:
        secondShip.append(i)
        secondShip.sort()


    return [
        [firstShip],
        [secondShip]
    ]
```

Comment: Indent it correctly and it will work.

Comment: Thanks ffor answering : Do you mean the return  command is incorrectly indented?

Comment: In Python, indentation matters. Your function indentation stops before `firstShip = []`, so the return statement at the bottom is considered out of the function body

Comment: In fact, the `return` statement is inside the *loop*.

Answer (score 2):

Indentation is important in Python. Make sure your code is properly indented:

```
def two_teams(sailors):

    sailors ={'Smith': 34,'Wesson': 22,'Coleman': 45,'davies' : 50,'Abrahams': 19,'Toms': 23}                                                                                                                           

    firstShip =[]

    secondShip = []

    for i in sailors.keys():
        if sailors[i] > 40 or sailors[i] < 20:
            firstShip.append(i)
            firstShip.sort()
        else:
            secondShip.append(i)
            secondShip.sort()

    return [
        [firstShip],
        [secondShip]
    ]
```

Comment: Although this corrected indentation the else is outside the for loop when it's meant to be inside and the spacing might cause issues on line 2 depending on python version

Comment: Thanks @AndreMotta, I was updating my answer

Comment: Thanks you are a great help. Worked a treat

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure wether it was your copy and pasting that caused this but in python you have to watch out for indentations and spaces between lines.

When you say

```
def double(x):
```

You need to follow up with a line right bellow it (Unless you are on jupyter)

```
def double(x):
    return 2*x
```

Also indentation needs to be correct for it to work.

```
def two_teams(sailors):
    sailors ={'Smith': 34,'Wesson': 22,'Coleman': 45,'davies' : 50,'Abrahams': 19, 'Toms': 23}                                                                                                                          
    firstShip =[]
    secondShip = []
    for i in sailors.keys():
        if sailors[i] > 40 or sailors[i] < 20:
            firstShip.append(i)
            firstShip.sort()
        else:
            secondShip.append(i)
            secondShip.sort()
    return [[firstShip],[secondShip]]
```

Tabs for each indentation level or 4 spaces. Please watch out and read a bit on python's spacing and indentation.